# Change the barTintColor after page load

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

Every view in my app has a different color. Setting this color works great. However, when I push to the next view (with its own color) and then return to the previous view.. the root view has a navbar BarTintColor set to the view I pushed to.

E.g.:
`Root view` *(red)* > `About view` *(green)* > (back to root) `Root view` *(green)*

How can I set the `barTintColor` when the page is already loaded? I have tried it using `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` but it doesn't change back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each of your view controllers , you can use following code in `viewDidAppear:` method :

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Your Desired Color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Tested the code in a sample project before suggesting ;)

Comment: Adding the `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];` to my `viewWillAppear` was sufficient enough. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use one of the Unwind Segue mechanisms (like put the unwind segue in your prepareForSegue: or use a delegate and execute it before your unwind happens...Make sense or do I need to go deeper?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't use Storyboard though cause I really don't like Storyboards. Its a good concept, but Apple is not there yet with implementing it, in my opinion.